# Doing both CPU and GPU mining on a machine?

Tags: cpu-mining, gpu-mining, mining, hashrate, mining-hardware

Is it possible for two miner softwares to be running on a machine? One doing CPU mining, other doing NVIDIA GPU mining? Can you share the names of the miners you use and the little about the hardware you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is totally doable. Just make sure to leave some CPU breathing room for the GPU miner application to feed the GPU with data by limiting the maximum threads used by the CPU miner.

Comment: Can you share the names of the miners you use and the little about the hardware you have?